# Не переносить таблицу на новую строку. CSS

Tags: css, html

Нужно, чтобы таблицы не переносились на новую строку при нехватке места в родительском элементе. При этом `width` родительского `div` не должен быть фиксированным.

```css
#header {
 border-top: 1px dotted #778899;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #778899;
 height:5.5em;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#header .links {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: firebrick;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1.5em;
 margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<table class="links">
  <tr>
    <td>1:</td>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="links">
  <tr>
    <td>2:</td>
    <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanatu/Ld2zfw1j/2/)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В целом обозначеная задача носит название *очистка потока css*.
Лично я использую `clearfix:after` для её реализации.

Пример:

```
.clearfix:after {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
}
```

Больше примеров: http://www.quizful.net/interview/css/PUKEaqIUub9Y